# CSSTransitionGroup __reactAutoBindMap error

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get started with React and CSSTransitionGroup. If I add my `<MyTransitionGroup ../>` I get the warning "Something is calling a React component directly", and the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined"

If I remove `<MyTransitionGroup ../>` - all is fine again. I checked the compiled js and `<MyTransitionGroup ../>` is compiled to `React.createElement(MyTransitionGroup...` - so it doesn't seem that the jsx compiler is out of date..

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var Addons = require('react-addons');
var MyTransitionGroup = Addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
var style = require('./Screen.scss');

var Screen = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var style = {
        backgroundColor: this.props.data.bgcolor
    };
    return (
        <MyTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true}> **// remove this and it works**
            <div style={style} className="Screen">
                {this.props.data.stitle}
            </div>
        </MyTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Screen;
```